# arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 160213: A networking error occurred

Tags: arcpy, arcgis-pro, arcgis-online

I'm trying to create a script to update a service on my ArcGIS Online account weekly but I've hit a road block when uploading. I thought at first it was that the service was too big, but I have now tried with a much simpler map and I get the same issue. I've also tried to run it on a couple of different computers to see if it was a PC or Firewall issue but I don't think that is the issue.

The script looks like:

```
import arcpy
import os

arcpy.SignInToPortal("https://www.arcgis.com", "", "")
arcpy.env.overwriteOutput = True

#Required Parameters
aprxFile = r"J:\projects\my_cfa\arcpro_project\MY_CFA\DEV_MY_CFA_v6.aprx"
mapName = 'Test'
service = 'DEV_MY_CFA_Layers'
save_location = r'J:\projects\my_cfa\arcpro_project\MY_CFA\AGOL_Data_Automation'
temp_location = r'J:\projects\my_cfa\arcpro_project\MY_CFA\temp data'

sddraft_output_filename = 'draft_service_definition.sddraft'

#Optional Parameters
share_public = True
share_organization = True
share_groups = None
overwriteService = True

summary = ''
tags = ''
description = ''

aprx = arcpy.mp.ArcGISProject(aprxFile)
m = aprx.listMaps(mapName)[0]

# Create FeatureSharingDraft and set service properties
sharing_draft = m.getWebLayerSharingDraft("HOSTING_SERVER", "FEATURE", service)
sharing_draft.summary = summary
sharing_draft.tags = tags
sharing_draft.description = description
sharing_draft.credits = "My Credits"
sharing_draft.useLimitations = "My Use Limitations"
sharing_draft.overwriteExistingService = overwriteService

# Create Service Definition Draft file
sharing_draft.exportToSDDraft(os.path.join(temp_location, sddraft_output_filename))
outsddraft = os.path.join(temp_location, sddraft_output_filename)
print("Service definition draft created")

# Create Service Definition file
sd_filename = service + ".sd"
sd_output_filename = os.path.join(save_location, sd_filename)
print("Start Stageing")
arcpy.StageService_server(outsddraft, sd_output_filename)

# Upload to portal
print("Start Uploading")
output = arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd_output_filename, "My Hosted Services", in_override="OVERRIDE_DEFINITION", in_public=share_public, in_organization=share_organization, in_groups=share_groups)
print("Service published")
```

but it fails at arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server with this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\smiles\AppData\Local\ESRI\conda\envs\arcgispro-py3-GeoPandas\lib\site-packages\IPython\core\interactiveshell.py", line 3437, in run_code
    exec(code_obj, self.user_global_ns, self.user_ns)
  File "<ipython-input-1-6db87ff510cb>", line 1, in <module>
    arcpy.UploadServiceDefinition_server(sd_output_filename, "My Hosted Services")
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\server.py", line 1227, in UploadServiceDefinition
    raise e
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\server.py", line 1224, in UploadServiceDefinition
    retval = convertArcObjectToPythonObject(gp.UploadServiceDefinition_server(*gp_fixargs((in_sd_file, in_server, in_service_name, in_cluster, in_folder_type, in_folder, in_startupType, in_override, in_my_contents, in_public, in_organization, in_groups), True)))
  File "C:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Pro\Resources\ArcPy\arcpy\geoprocessing\_base.py", line 512, in <lambda>
    return lambda *args: val(*gp_fixargs(args, True))
arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 160213: A networking error occurred.
Failed to execute (UploadServiceDefinition).
```

does anyone have any pointer to fix this issue?

Comment: https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/tool-reference/tool-errors-and-warnings/160001-170000/tool-errors-and-warnings-160201-160225-160213.htm

Comment: I did have a look at that, but I don't know how to change the heap size of a hosted service on ArcGIS Online. I did think it may have been the issue which is why I tried to use a much simpler map which mean the service definition file was only 4mb instead of the initial ~70mb

Answer (score 0):

I worked out the issue was with a lack of permissions for organisations AGOL account. I had an admin run my script and it worked straight away.